# laravel how to save files with predefined name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

in laravel controller i am trying to give each video file i uploading should be rename as

```
**myfile.mp4**
```

and save in public folder.

but my present code makes random number for my files but i need to give name as **myfile**

my controller

```
$input['file_id'] = time() . '.' . $request->file_id->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder1 = public_path('/public');
        $path1 = $folder1 . $input['file_id']; // path 1
        $request->file_id->move($folder1, $input['file_id']);
```

Comment: The random number is due to the time() function you are using.

Comment: @Atchiiii how to time()  remove and add myfile . help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is :

```
$input['file_id'] = 'myfile.'.$request->file_id->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

But you cannot give the same name 'myfile' to all your videos because each recording will be overwritten by the previous one, you need unique names.
For this you can do, for example:

```
 $input['file_id'] = 'myfile'.time().'.'.$request->file_id->getClientOriginalExtension();
 // here, time() represents the time at which the video was saved in your '/public' file
```

or

```
 $input['file_id'] = 'myfile'.date().'.'.$request->file_id->getClientOriginalExtension();
 // here, date() represents the date the video was saved in your '/public' file
```

Comment: i tryid your answer but it passing time like this myfile1611659509.mp4, but i need myfile.mp4 this only

Comment: @user12380208 Ok, as you like. So try this : `$input['file_id'] = 'myfile.'.$request->file_id->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: @ Atchiiii update this $input['file_id'] = 'myfile.'.$request->file_id->getClientOriginalExtension(); in your answer thank you

Comment: @user12380208 It's done. You can mark it as an answer